# работа с cURL через proxy

Tags: php, curl

используется код

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy_port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $username . ":" . $password)
```

работа производится через proxy.
при работе с протоколами `http` все работает прекрасно . но при работе с `https` на сервере `proxy` ошибка что не прошла авторизация . но если убрать имя пользователя или пароль в поле  `CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD`  выдает ошибку что нет подключения ,следовательно можно предположить что подключение работает . так вот интересно почему на сервере требует авторизацию , или может есть какой отдельный параметр для авторизации для работы с протоколом `HTTPS`.
так же пробовал строки :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLFTPSSL_TRY); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

думал в сторону строки `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP')` , по документации не нашел что можно вставить `HTTPS`

Answer (score 1):

Этот параметр отвечает за туннелирование запроса, в данном случае proxy
Добавьте

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Comment: не совсем понял что вы имеете ввиду , можете подробнее объяснить ?

Comment: CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, говорит что сейчас будет работа через прокси